# Function in constructors as parameters[object not declared yet]

Tags: java

I'm having a huge problem here

```
public class Attendant {

    //Max. amount = 10
    public int staffNum = 10;
    private String[] id;
    private boolean available;
    private attNm name;



    /**
     * @param staffNum
     * @param strings
     * @param available
     * @param name
     */
    public Attendant(int staffNum, String[] id, boolean available, attNm name) {
        this.staffNum = staffNum;
        this.id = id;
        this.available = available;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String[] getID(){

        String[] tempArray = new String[staffNum];

        for(int x=0; x<staffNum;x++){
            tempArray[x] = ("Att" + (x+1));
            System.out.println(tempArray[x]);
            }

        return tempArray;
        }               
}
```

This above is my attendent class
Just below is my main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static void createAtt(){

        for(int x=0; x<10;x++){
            Attendant att = new Attendant(x+1, att.getID(), true, attNm.Emma);
        }           
    }
}
```

My problem is I need to create 10 attendant from the constructor. But the IDs are from the attendant class. Technically I think I have to declare an attendant first.
But here it needs to get the ID from an array which is from its class.
and furthermore it should get one ID only at each iteration of the loop.(each iteration take the next ID from the array)

If possible also:
is there a way to get a method in a enum class to send or use so that i can call it as parameter.[In mine its emma just to test]

I really dont know how to figure these.
I cant find something similar on google.
please.

Comment: refer my answer below, ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/39523217/504133)     hopefully it will help you to understand the cause and a possible solution for your issue, it shall be helpful for this case and othersuch scenarios in future. If your issue is resolved the  you may mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many things to be taken care of, namely:

1. Your code won't run as main() is empty
2. Your Attendant class doesn't needs an array of ids.

This is how your Attendant class should look like:

```
public class Attendant {
    private String id; // not an array
    // your rest of fields

    public Attendant(int staffNum, String id, boolean available, attNm name) {
        // modified --------------- ^^^^^^^^
    }

    //accessors, so on for the others
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be the ID needed here is an array.

Answer (score 1):

I see your main method as empty but I feel you will write code in it once your issue is resolved. So now moving on to your issue.

**Issue cause**
The mistake you are doing is before creation of an object you are trying to extract something from it, hence the reference refers to null and then you want execution of a method on an object (null) referred by the reference.

**Solution**
Seprate the circular dependency. For object creation you need to invoke `getID()` and to invoke `getID()` you want the object to be created.
Though there are various ways to solve this, below is one of the ways in which you can solve your issue.

Declare `getID()` as `static method` in class `Attendant.java` and take `staffNum` as method parameter. Now you can call this method without need of object. You just need to use `dot operator` with `Attendant` class name.

summarizing :

1. declare `getID()` as  `static` and add `staffNum` as parameter.
   `public static String[] getID(int staffNum)`
2. Modify the code inside for loop.

`Attendant att = new Attendant(x+1, Attendant.getID(x+1), true, attNm.Emma);`

Answer (score 1):

Move your getId() to your main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int staffNum = 10;
    String []ids = getID(staffNum); 
    for(int x=0; x<staffNum;x++){
       Attendant att = new Attendant(x+1, ids[x], true, attNm.Emma);
    }
}



public static String[] getID(int staffNum){

  String[] tempArray = new String[staffNum];

  for(int x=0; x<staffNum;x++){
      tempArray[x] = ("Att" + (x+1));
      System.out.println(tempArray[x]);
  }

  return tempArray;
}

}
}
```

And also change your Attendant to get a String id instead of an array.

```
public Attendant(int staffNum, String id, boolean available, attNm name) {
   this.staffNum = staffNum;
   this.id = id;
   this.available = available;
   this.name = name;
```

}

Comment: Pretty sure you haven't tested your code, this line has syntax error: `String []ids = getID();`